# Mysql: help in query from two tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables: users,friends thus structured:

Users:

```
+------------+--------------+.  
| users_id   | username     |.  
+------------+--------------+.  
| 1          | Mark         |.  
| 2          | Alex         |.  
| 3          | Anna         |.  
+------------+--------------+.
```

Friends:

```
+------------+--------------+.  
| id |fromid |  toid        |.  
+------------+--------------+.  
| 1  |    2  |     3        |.  
| 2  |    1  |     2        |.  
| 3  |    1  |     3        |.  
+------------+--------------+.
```

What's the query to retrieve these results:

```
+------------+--------------+.  
| from       |     to       |    
+------------+--------------+.  
| Alex       | Anna         |    
| Mark       | Alex         |.  
| Mark       | Anna         |.  
+------------+--------------+.
```

P.s.: excuse me if tables are not properly formatted in my question

Comment: Hint:  You need two joins, one on `fromid` and one on `toid`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT u1.name as from_name,
       u2.name as to_name
FROM Friends AS f
JOIN Users AS u1 ON u1.users_id = f.fromid
JOIN Users AS u2 ON u2.users_id = f.toid
```

This would do.